# Bind a SharePoint list to a Silverlight Dataform

Tags: silverlight-4.0, sharepoint-2010, dataform

I am using the SharePoint client-object model to read data from a list and I was finally able to correctly get the data but now I am having difficulty actually displaying that data. I would like to use a dataform control to both add and edit the SharePoint list but am thus far unable to get it to actually display the items in the list. If anyone knows how to connect a Dataform control to a sharepoint list I would be very thankful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to bind your list to the control. Have a look at the following page: http://dotnetslackers.com/articles/silverlight/The-DataForm-Control-in-Silverlight-3-Revisited.aspx section "Data binding" explains the steps you need to make (setting the DataContext property).

Comment: Thank you very much everything that I could find said to set the ItemSource instead which wasn't working.